# how to get object value on button click in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am displaying a list view in angular using ng-repeat .I an able to display list .Actually there is one radio button in each row .And I have one button on screen .I want to get object of selected radio button on button click .In other words If I select first row radio button then if I click button I need get it object how I will achieve this ?

here is my code

```
<table>

    <tr id="$index"ng-repeat= "a in data " ng-click="getselectedRow(a)">
        <td> {{a.condidateID}} </td>
        <td> {{a.condidateName}} </td>
        <td> {{a.territory}} </td>
        <td> {{a.voteCount}} </td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="egg" ng-model="chekratiovalue"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
        <button style="left: 40%;top: 40%;float: left;position: relative" ng-click="voteForPerson()">Vote</button>
```

**Update**

```
 function userdetail($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams){
        console.log(JSON.parse($routeParams.userDetail));
        var userDetail=JSON.parse($routeParams.userDetail);
        $scope.data=userDetail.data;
        console.log($scope.data);
        console.log($scope.data);
        $scope.changeEvnt = function(index) {
            $scope.activeRow = index;
            alert( $scope.activeRow);
        }

        $scope.voteForPerson = function() {
            var selcted = $scope.data[activeRow ];
        }
    }


<table>

    <tr id="$index"ng-repeat= "a in data " ng-click="getselectedRow(a)">
        <td> {{a.condidateID}} </td>
        <td> {{a.condidateName}} </td>
        <td> {{a.territory}} </td>
        <td> {{a.voteCount}} </td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="egg" ng-model="chekratiovalue" ng-change="changeEvnt($index)"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
        <button style="left: 40%;top: 40%;float: left;position: relative" ng-click="voteForPerson()">Vote</button>
```

Comment: You need to pass $index to your click function.

Comment: where to pass ?button is no screen and radio button on each row.only one radio button is selected at one time

Answer (score 1):

add `ng-change` directive,

```
<input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="egg" ng-model="chekratiovalue" ng-change="chengeEvnt($index)">
```

In controller

```
$scope.chengeEvnt = function(index) {
    $scope.activeRow = index;     // get the index when changing the radio button
}

$scope.voteForPerson = function() {
     var selected = $scope.data[$scope.activeRow];   // get the row of selected radio button using the `$scope.activeRow` function
}
```

Comment: please check that update ..and I will apply your anser

Comment: sir actually your edited anser also work only first time .Mean when I select first row it give 0 index.then I select second row it give 1 index (deselect the first row).but again when i select first row again it not give alert mean on change event not fire

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is not firing second time

Comment: ok I will take static data because I am getting data from local webservice and used plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63743/discussion-between-user944513-and-kalhano-toress-pamuditha).

Comment: yes click is working fine :) dont know the reason :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the $parent notation when you click the radio button inside ng-repeat.

```
 <table>

    <tr id="$index" ng-repeat= "a in data ">
        <td> {{a.condidateID}} </td>
        <td> {{a.condidateName}} </td>
        <td> {{a.territory}} </td>
        <td> {{a.voteCount}} </td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="{{a.chekratiovalue}}" ng-model="$parent.chekratiovalue"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

This is required as ng-repeat creates its own scope.

[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2VcNBHausstkZ3SfxxC?p=preview)

Comment: @user944513: Did this help u?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use

```
ng-value="item"
```

and you can get any info you want from there.

**Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cUaXWaLiVu5LtuoalG6Z?p=preview)**